# non-recursive version Permutations

Tags: python, recursion, combinations, permutation

I have two functions, `prod` and `perm`. They are very similar.Both of them using the recursive.Now I wan't replace recursion with for loop. `prod2` worked correct, but `perm2` doesn't, How can I fix it?

```
#Recursive version:

def prod(A,k):
    return [[]] if k==0 else [[a]+b for a in A for b in prod(A,k-1)]

def perm(A,k):
    return [[]] if k==0 else [[a]+b for a in A for b in perm([i for i in A if i!=a],k-1)]


#NonRecursive version:

def prod2(A,k):
    r=[[]]
    for i in range(k):
        r=[[a]+b for a in A for b in r]
    return r

def perm2(A,k):
    r=[[]]
    for i in range(k):
        r=[[a]+b for a in A for b in [i for i in r if i!=a ] ]
    return r

print prod([1,2,3],2)
print prod2([1,2,3],2)

print perm([1,2,3],2)
print perm2([1,2,3],2)
```

Comment: On another note, if you want to do permutations and products in Python, rather than just implemention them to improve your skill,  the itertools module is the way forward.

Comment: Your recursive `perm` also wrong. Works only for `k=2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `r` variable in your code contains lists, `i != a` will always be `True`. Here is how to fix it:

```
def perm2(A, k):
    r = [[]]
    for i in range(k):
        r = [[a] + b for a in A for b in [i for i in r if a not in i]]
    return r
```

Or simply:

```
def perm2(A, k):
    r = [[]]
    for i in range(k):
        r = [[a] + b for a in A for b in r if a not in b]
    return r
```

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful solution guys, here's a rewrite which works with Numba:

```
@numba.njit()
def permutations(A, k):
    r = [[i for i in range(0)]]
    for i in range(k):
        r = [[a] + b for a in A for b in r if (a in b)==False]
    return r
permutations([1,2,3],3)
```